# How can I use DebugBreak() in C#?

Tags: c#, debugging, debugbreak

What is the syntax and which namespace/class needs to be imported? Give me sample code if possible. It would be of great help.

Answer (score 46):

I also like to check to see if the debugger is attached - if you call Debugger.Break when there is no debugger, it will prompt the user if they want to attach one.   Depending on the behavior you want, you may want to call Debugger.Break() only if (or if not) one is already attached

```
using System.Diagnostics;

//.... in the method:

if( Debugger.IsAttached) //or if(!Debugger.IsAttached)
{
  Debugger.Break();
}
```

Answer (score 25):

Put the following where you need it:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Answer (score 8):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.break#System_Diagnostics_Debugger_Break

```
#if DEBUG
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
#endif
```

Comment: Great +1 for `#if DEBUG`! It's awfully when dev. leaves this code in release.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` to break in a specific place. This can help in situations like debugging a service.

Answer (score 3):

The answers from @Philip Rieck and @John are subtly different.

John's ...

```
#if DEBUG
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
#endif
```

only works if you compiled with the DEBUG conditional compilation symbol set.

Phillip's answer ...

```
if( Debugger.IsAttached) //or if(!Debugger.IsAttached)
{
  Debugger.Break();
}
```

will work for any debugger so you will give any hackers a bit of a fright too.

Also take note of `SecurityException` it can throw so don't let that code out into the wild.

Another reason no to ...

> If no debugger is attached, users are asked if they want to attach a
>   debugger. If users say yes, the debugger is started. If a debugger is
>   attached, the debugger is signaled with a user breakpoint event, and
>   the debugger suspends execution of the process just as if a debugger
>   breakpoint had been hit.

from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx