# Breakpoint not working for SOSEX using !mbp

Tags: windbg, sos, sosex

I'm trying to debug a C# application using [SOSEX](http://www.stevestechspot.com/SOSEXV40NowAvailable.aspx) in WinDbg for 32 bit environment in .NET Framework 4.0. I use sosex.dll for 32 bit v4.0.

Here are the steps:

1. `sxe ld:mscorlib`
2. `sxe ld:clrjit`
3. `load` *Path to sosex.dll*
4. `!mbp application.cs 34` (this sets breakpoint at line 34)

It works fine here.

However, when I start WinDbg fresh and attach to the C# `application.exe` process and do the necessary steps, the breakpoint doesn't work.

One thing I have observed is that the first time I ran the `lm` command in WinDbg, the output showed only `application.exe`.

But the next time, the `lm` command showed all the modules already loaded (`clrjit`, `mscorlib`, etc.)

Is this why the breakpoint isn't working?

Comment: If there are any details from your [earlier question on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244012/breakpoint-doesnt-work-in-windbg-using-sosex) that you want to add to this question, please [edit] this question and add them here.

Comment: Did you check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768921/breakpoint-set-by-sosex-mbp-or-sosex-mbm-not-working)?

Answer (score 0):

With SOSEX, steps 1 and 2 above are unnecessary. If you launch an application from the debugger, you can use `!mbm` and `!mbp` from the initial breakpoint.

As for your problem, what is located at `application.cs`, line 34? Is this the entry point (Main)? It sounds like you're trying to break after the code has already run. Please attach all the debugger spew from your attempt to break. This will help to pinpoint the cause of the problem.

Comment: it's a simple method called print() inside main() that prints "hello" at console. Breakpoint is set at this method. Before this method there is Console.ReadKey() so that when this key is hit in application, print() method is called.

Comment: Can you tell if the Print method has been inlined?  Feel free to contact me offline.  If sosex is broken, I'd like to fix it.