# setting a breakpoint in windbg using a script

Tags: windbg

I would like to create a script in windbg that sets a breakpoint in System.Windows.Forms.Application+MarshalingControl..ctor and when that breakpoint is being hit, it just dumps the stack trace into a log file that i open.

I'm using the sos extension's !Name2EE command to get the JITTED code address, but i still don't have a way to get the exact address from what is being returned:

`.block{.shell -ci "!Name2EE *!System.Windows.Forms.Application+MarshalingControl..ctor" FIND "JITTED Code Address:"}`

but this returns: `JITTED Code Address: 63348434` 
Where i would like to get only the address number itself.

Any suggestions?

Comment: want some  hack on hack  try this :) 0:004> .shell -ci "!Name2EE * Console.WriteLine" grep J | head -n 2 
JITTED Code Address: 5cc859ac
JITTED Code Address: 5d2e52f4
.shell: Process exited
0:004> .shell -ci "!Name2EE * Console.WriteLine" grep J | head -n 2  | awk "{print $4}"
5cc859ac
5d2e52f4
.shell: Process exited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Getting the jitted address

You can surround that by a `.foreach` which eats the words `JITTED Code Address:` by using `/pS 3` (initial skip) and eats `.shell: Process exited` by `/ps 3` (skip):

I tried with

```
0:000> .foreach /pS 3 /ps 3 (var {.shell -ci ".echo JITTED Code Address: 63348434" FIND "JITTED Code Address:"}) {.echo ${var}}
63348434
```

You should use

```
.block{.foreach /pS 3 /ps 3(var {.shell -ci "!Name2EE *!System.Windows.Forms.Application+MarshalingControl..ctor" FIND "JITTED Code Address:"}) {.echo ${var}}}
```

and then change `.echo ${var}` to whatever you like to do with the address.

Be aware of edge cases: the method may not have been jitted yet.

### Managed breakpoint

I wonder a bit why you want to put a breakpoint at the jitted address and why a [sosex](/questions/tagged/sosex) managed breakpoint does not work for you. Have you tried `!mbm` and `!mbp`?

Comment: Related if `!mbm` does not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768921/breakpoint-set-by-sosex-mbp-or-sosex-mbm-not-working

Comment: Thanks Thomas! You're suggestion worked.
I'm still new with WinDBG's options - so didn't even know sosex exists.

By the way, is there an option to run WinDBG in sort of a silent mode? let it just run a script without opening the WinDBG's UI?

Comment: @Ziv: There's `cdb`, the console debugger. If you add a statement like `q` at the end of your script, it should exit automatically. Still possible it opens a console window.