# WinDbg sosex unable to debug

Tags: c#, windbg

I am trying to debug managed code. `.exe` file is build for `x64`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DebugTutorial
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Foo2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo2");
        }

        public static void Foo1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo1");
        }

        public static void Parent()
        {
            Foo1();
            Console.WriteLine("Parent");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo1();
            Foo2();
            Parent();
        }
    }
}
```

I am doing next commands:

```
0:000> .load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
0:000> .load C:\Users\Anton\Downloads\sosex_64\sosex.dll
0:000> .symfix
0:000> .reload /f
Reloading current modules
.*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for DebugTutorial.exe
....
0:000> lm
start             end                 module name
00000252`916b0000 00000252`916b6000   DebugTutorial C (pdb symbols)          C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\DebugTutorial.pdb\B430DC1915A0462AB2D21E18458D70E71\DebugTutorial.pdb
00007ffb`233a0000 00007ffb`23404000   MSCOREE    (pdb symbols)          C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\mscoree.pdb\02E66277C518120A967A3BFBC1850C941\mscoree.pdb
00007ffb`30280000 00007ffb`304f3000   KERNELBASE   (pdb symbols)          C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\kernelbase.pdb\CD6C76E6120253287103CD7E22CC0A5D1\kernelbase.pdb
00007ffb`32900000 00007ffb`329b1000   KERNEL32   (pdb symbols)          C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\kernel32.pdb\CA130BEBF44E36EAC20C5E95752843F61\kernel32.pdb
00007ffb`33ca0000 00007ffb`33e81000   ntdll      (pdb symbols)          C:\ProgramData\dbg\sym\ntdll.pdb\95927C40B68E505CD22742795247114C1\ntdll.pdb
0:000> !mbp DebugTutorial Foo1
The CLR has not yet been initialized in the process.
Breakpoint resolution will be attempted when the CLR is initialized.
0:000> .load C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
0:000> .reload /f
Reloading current modules
.*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for DebugTutorial.exe
....
0:000> !mbp DebugTutorial Foo1
The breakpoint could not be set because a breakpoint has already been specified for this source location.
```

If I place breakpoin with F9 hotkey I see next

```
0:000> g
Unable to insert breakpoint 0 at 00000252`916b002e, Win32 error 0n998
    "Invalid access to memory location."
bp0 at 00000252`916b002e failed
WaitForEvent failed
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x31:
00007ffb`33d6c93d eb00            jmp     ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x33 (00007ffb`33d6c93f)
```

> Win32 error 0n998

Why? What is happening? How to debug .net with windbg?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12018376/4137916) has some useful things to try out/consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.load ...\clr.dll` is attempting to load the .NET framework as a plugin for WinDbg. That won't work. The .NET plugin for WinDbg is called SOS and you usually do `.loadby sos clr`. However, that should not matter much for the rest of the session.

First, you're using `!mbp`, which is used with source file and line number. However, you use it with module and method.

Second, even for `!mbm`, the parameters `DebugTutorial Foo1` are incorrect. The format is `module!namespace.class.method`. Luckily you can use wildcards. Try `!mbm *!*method`

Third, IMHO you get a better feedback of whether your command works or not, if the .NET framework is already loaded and about jitting. Use `sxe ld clrjit` to achieve that.

So here we go:

```
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ffd`fe112cfc cc              int     3
0:000> sxe ld clrjit
0:000> *** Wait until .NET is loaded
0:000> g

(3bc4.33bc): Unknown exception - code 04242420 (first chance)
ModLoad: 00007ffd`d2530000 00007ffd`d265b000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
ntdll!NtMapViewOfSection+0x14:
00007ffd`fe0dfb94 c3              ret
0:000> .load E:\...\sosex.dll
0:000> !mbm *!*Foo1
0:000> !mbl
0 e : disable *!*FOO1 ILOffset=0: pass=1 oneshot=false thread=ANY
    SODebugMBP!DebugTutorial.Program.Foo1() (PENDING JIT)

0:000> g

Breakpoint: JIT notification received for method DebugTutorial.Program.Foo1() in AppDomain 0000028c1a58ea00.
Breakpoint set at DebugTutorial.Program.Foo1() in AppDomain 0000028c1a58ea00.
Breakpoint 2 hit
00007ffd`730804e8 90              nop
0:000> !clrstack
OS Thread Id: 0x13d4 (0)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
000000d4d8afeaa0 00007ffd730804e8 DebugTutorial.Program.Foo1() [C:\...\Program.cs @ 14]
000000d4d8afead0 00007ffd730804a2 DebugTutorial.Program.Main(System.String[]) [C:\...\Program.cs @ 26]
000000d4d8afed30 00007ffdd2666da3 [GCFrame: 000000d4d8afed30]
```