# How to attach to running python script via PTVS at beginning of execution

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I want to attach to a python script that is called by another program (.exe).

I am developing the python script.

Right now, I am using (Python 2.7)

```
raw_input("Press Enter to continue and/or attach debugger...")
```

to make the script wait and attach the debugger.

**Is there some convenient way, like C#**

```
Debugger.Break()
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/105599/586754 ) **to directly prompt me to attach with the already open Visual Studio instance?** Manually attaching (especially when doing many runs) takes some time. I have done it so often I even know Ctrl+Alt+P to open the attach dialog (then click in program list, hit p for python, click attach..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing currently. Feel free to [file a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvs/issues).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Perhaps it is something easy. https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/853